# Create an image of a website page live look

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am not sure if this is even possible. But I want to make a login page something similar to this:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrTUn.png) Using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Now as the background image, I want that to display how another website looks like like. If I take for example google.com as an example. I want the background image to display exactly what you see when visiting google.com. Is something like this even possible?

Comment: That is possible, but can you explain this `background image to display exactly what you see when visiting google.com`,

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with HTML. Create a page with whatever background image you want with a Login form defined with your CSS in the middle of the page. Then submit the page to wherever you process the login.

```
`<body style="background-image: url('image_path.jpg');" action="process_login.php" method="post">
    <form class="loginForm" name="loginForm">
        <!-- Form elements -->
    </form>
</body>`
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you look into [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), they provide the exact functionality that you are looking for. You would just need to position it in the background with a div + some css.

Comment: This is not an answer... You should post this as a comment .